# Contexts and Fallbacks on Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible to set fallback intents using only contexts?

The example would be the user asks a question which triggers fallback intent 1 "sorry I don't understand"

The user then tries again with a reformulation of the question which then triggers fall back intent 2 "hmmm I still don't understand you, please leave your email and someone will get back to you right away"

I have tried adding contexts but it is always the default fallback intent that is triggered

Answer (score 0):

You can use fulfillment code to give response like that.

For this you need to set a counter for fallback occurance.

then according to counter variable you can reply with different text each time fallback has occured.